# How to change the dns using command prompt?

Tags: windows, dns

I can't change my dns using the gui. Does anyone know how to change the DNS using command prompt in windows? Thanks

Comment: And why exactly is it not possible for you to use the GUI?

Answer (score 2):

Open up CMD with Administrator Privileges, then type **netsh**

If you want to change DNS address only means..then try this

**interface ip set dns “Local Area Connection” static 192.168.1.1**

Here, Local Area Connection is your Ethernet Card's name.

If you want to change the IP address also then

**interface ip set address name=”Local Area Connection” static 192.168.10.42 255.255.255.0 192.168.1.1**